# Python Flask - url_for{} not accessing static folder

Tags: python, css, flask, directory

Have a directory structure as follows:

```
Flask_project
-env
-src
--app2.py
-static
--css
---main.css
-templates
--base.html
--index.html
-app.py
```

If I load the page using app.py in the main folder, the main.css file is loaded fine using: `python app.py`. This works from the following file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for # import

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, if I load app2.py using python3 `src\app2.py` which is in the \src folder as follows, and redirects the template_folder:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for # import

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am unable to load the css\main.css folder, I get the following error:

```
"GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I don't see why placing the app_whatever.py file in a sub directory (in this case \src) makes it unable to locate the main.css file?

For reference the `base.html` is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
        {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And `index.html` is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1> Template </h1>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912743/flask-python-not-loading-main-css/67913059#67913059), you need to define the location of your `static`-folder:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
```