# Flask Python not loading main.css

Tags: python, css, flask

Have a file structure as follows:

[image]

app.py and app2.py are nearly identical, except app2.py directs to the templates folder due to app2.py being in the \src folder.

app.py:

[image]

app2.py:

[image]

When loading via app.py, everything runs fine and the main.css is found. However, when running app2.py (inside the src directory), flask can't find the main.css and returns an error: "

> GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Not sure what's going on as the files are nearly identical.

Index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1> Template </h1>
    
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
        {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `GET /static/css/main2.css` Is that url correct?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question as I had changed it to main2.css to see if it was a naming issue but that wasn't it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you also need to pass the `static`-folder location:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove css/ from this code line it is working in my case

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
```